# values.map is not a function Sequelize

Tags: forms, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to send a form to my db but I get this error :

[The problem XD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwdIi.png)

I have this problem only when I try to do it from the front, because when I try with Insomnia it works. So I'm not sure where the problem is coming from.

I'm using multer for the image.

The model:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
// Exportamos una funcion que define el modelo
// Luego le injectamos la conexion a sequelize.
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  // defino el modelo
  sequelize.define('Recipe', {
    id:{
      type: DataTypes.UUID(5),
      primaryKey:true,
      defaultValue:DataTypes.UUIDV4(5)
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    summary:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    healthScore:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    steps:{
     type:DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    },
    dishTypes:{
      type:DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    },
    readyInMinutes:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      get(){
          return "Ready in " + this.getDataValue("readyInMinutes") + " minutes"
      }
    },
    ingredients:{
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    },
    servings:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING
    },
    image:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: `https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/food-still-life-salmon-keto-healthy-eating-732x549-thumbnail-732x549.jpg`
    }
  },{
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

The post route (actually the helper):

```
const createNewRecipe = require("../helpers/RecipeCont/CreateRecipe/CreateRecipe")

const createNewRecipeRoute = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      
      const data = {
        title,
        summary,
        healthScore,
        steps,
        dishTypes,
        readyInMinutes,
        ingredients,
        servings,
        Diet_type,
      } = req.body;
      const image = req.file.path
      let newRecipe = await createNewRecipe({
        title,
        summary,
        healthScore,
        steps,
        dishTypes,
        readyInMinutes,
        ingredients,
        servings,
        image,
      });
      await newRecipe.addDiet_type(Diet_type) 
       console.log(req.file)
      res.status(200).json("Receta creada con éxito");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(400).json(error.message);

    }
  }

  module.exports = createNewRecipeRoute;
```

The form

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createRecipe, getDietTypes } from "../../actions/actions";
import styles from "./form.module.css"



export default function Form(){
    const [form,setForm] = useState({
        title:"",
        summary:"",
        healthScore:0,
        steps:[],
        dishTypes:[],
        readyInMinutes:0,
        ingredients:[],
        servings:0,
        image:"",
        Diet_type:[1]

    })
    const [steps, setSteps] = useState("")
    const [dishTypes, setDishType]=useState("")
    const [ingredients, setIngredients]= useState("")


const dispatch=useDispatch()
useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getDietTypes())
},[])
const diets = useSelector(state=> state.diet)
    

   const changeHandler=(e)=>{
    if(e.target.name==="image"){
        setForm({...form,[e.target.name]: e.target.file })
    }
        setForm({...form, [e.target.name]:e.target.value}) 
          
    }
    const stepHandler = (e)=>{
        let aux = e.target.name
        let auxV = e.target.value
        if(e.key==="Enter"){
            e.preventDefault()
            
            setForm({...form, [e.target.name]: [...form[aux] , auxV ]})
            aux==="steps"? setSteps("") : aux==="ingredients"? setIngredients("") : setDishType("")

        }
        console.log(form)
    }
    const deleteHandler = (e)=>{
        let help = e.target.name
        e.preventDefault()
        let aux = form[help].filter(s=> s!==e.target.value)
        setForm({...form, [help]: [...aux]})
    }
    const imageHandler = (e)=>{

        
        setForm({...form, [e.target.name]:e.target.files[0]})
    }
    const sendHandler = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(form.image!==""){
        const formData = new FormData()
        
        formData.append("image",form.image)
        formData.append("title",form.title)
        formData.append("summary",form.summary)
        formData.append("healthScore",form.healthScore)
        formData.append("steps",form.steps)
        formData.append("dishTypes",form.dishTypes)
        formData.append("readyInMinutes",form.readyInMinutes)
        formData.append("Ingredients",form.ingredients)
        formData.append("servings",form.servings)
        formData.append("Diet_type",form.Diet_type)
        
        for (var key of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
        }
        dispatch(createRecipe(formData))
        } else {
            dispatch(createRecipe(form))
        }

        console.log(form)

    }
    return(
        <>
        <div className={styles.div} >
        <h2>Create your own recipe!</h2>
        <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit={sendHandler}>
            <div className={styles.divTitle}>
                <h2>Title:</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" value={form.title} onChange={changeHandler}></input>
            </div>
            
            <input type="text" placeholder="summary" name="summary" value={form.summary} onChange={changeHandler}></input>
            {form.healthScore}<input type="range" placeholder="healthScore" name="healthScore" min="1" max="100" step="1" value={form.healthScore} onChange={changeHandler} ></input>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="steps" value={steps} onChange={(e)=>{setSteps(e.target.value)}} onKeyDown={stepHandler} placeholder="Steps"></input>
            <div>
                {form.steps.length>0? form.steps.map(e=><li>{e}<button value={e} name="steps" onClick={deleteHandler}>x</button></li>) : "Add the steps of your recipe!"}
            </div>    
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="ingredients" value={ingredients} onChange={(e)=>{setIngredients(e.target.value)}} onKeyDown={stepHandler} placeholder="Ingredients"></input>
            <div>
                {form.ingredients.length>0? form.ingredients.map(e=><li>{e}<button value={e} name="ingredients" onClick={deleteHandler}>x</button></li>) : "Add the ingredients of your recipe!"}
            </div>    
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="dishTypes" value={dishTypes} onChange={(e)=>{setDishType(e.target.value)}} onKeyDown={stepHandler} placeholder="Dish types"></input>
            <div>
                {form.dishTypes.length>0? form.dishTypes.map(e=><li>{e}<button value={e} onClick={deleteHandler}>x</button></li>) : "Add the dish types of your recipe!"}
            </div>    
            </div>
            <select>
                {console.log(diets)}
                
                {diets?.map(d=><option key={d.id} id={d.id}>{d.name}</option>)}
            </select>
            <input className={styles.number} name="readyInMinutes" value={form.readyInMinutes} onChange={changeHandler} type="number"></input>
            <input className={styles.number} name="servings" value={form.servings} onChange={changeHandler} type="number"></input>
            <input type="file"  name="image" onChange={imageHandler}></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I'm still working on the form, in Diet_type for example, but even trying to hardcode the state to make the post it doesn't work.

The "for" is because the console.log doesn't work with formData and at the beginning I thought it was that I wasn't sending anything, but actually I do.

I save the image of all the request even for those which can fulfill so the middleware seems its working too.

I hope you can help me to understand what's going on and try to find a solution, c: Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

The object values does not have the map methode.

You expect that there should be a map methode, but this is not a javascipt array with protype map. So you get the error.

You can use the loadash library.

```
const {map} require(`lodash`)

map(values, value => {
console.log(value)
// your code coes here
}
```